# Diacritic characters in C char arrays or strings

Tags: c, string, xc8

**Background**

Im working on some embedded project and Im trying to handle non-standard characters and font.

I have raw bitmap font in 600+ element array. Every 5 elements of this array contain one character. I have character 32 (space) in first 5 elements, 33 character (!) in 6-10 elements etc.

I have to handle national diacritic characters ("ę" for example). I located them after 122 character. Now im trying to remap characters, to get proper character printed when I type `print("Test ę");` in C source.

**Problem**

So I want to type like this in source:

```
print("Test diactric ę");
// warning: (228) illegal character (0xC4)
```

When I try this (I tried to see what code C will put for "ę"):

```
int a = 'ę';
// error: (226) char const too long
```

**How to workaround this?**

Im using XC8 compiler (gcc based?).

I found in compiler manual, that it uses 7-bit character encoding, but maybe there is some way? My source file is encoded in UTF-8.

**EDIT**

Looks like wchar.h suggested by Emilien could work for me, but unfortunately there is no wchar.h for my compiler.

Maybe some preprocessor trick? I really want to avoid hardcore text preparation like this:

```
print("abcde");
print_diactric(123); // 123 code used for ę
print("fgh");

// to get "abcdeęf" "word"
```

Comment: A `char` is just a small `int` of size 1 byte; it can only hold 256 different values (0 ~ 255, -128 ~ +127, etc.). For pretty much anything other than english text, you'll need some sort of multi-byte characters/strings (e.g. Unicode).

Comment: @NicolasMiari It's not correct to say that it's "just a small `int`", since `int` is signed and the signedness of `char` is more complicated. It can be either.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to reinvent this particular wheel?

Comment: @unwind yes, perhaps I should have worded it as  "a special, very small _integer type_, signed/or unsigned depending on the implementation" to avoid confusion with "`int`" (usually 4 bytes).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Im not reinventing, I just have LCD display without character generator.

Comment: It looks like you are reinventing Unicode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No. I need few characters from 16-bit encoding in 8-bit system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about the difference between the *source encoding* (what it sounds like, the character encoding used by your C source files on the system where the compiler runs) and the *target encoding*, which is the encoding that the compiler assumes for the system where the code will be running.

If your compiler's target encoding is "7-bit", then there's no standard way to express a character like ę, it's simply not part of the target charset. You're going to have to work around that, perhaps by implementing the encoding by yourself from some other format.

Comment: For characters in the 128-255 range, you can use hex codes, e.g. '\xE2`

Comment: This ought to work but the OP also needs to create a translation table from UTF8 (input format) to output format (2-byte index in the "600+" bitmap table). Depending on the range of *output* characters, use either a linear list (for consecutive codes) or a binary table (for more random characters) of Unicode values.

Answer (score 1):

As unwind explained, you'll need for than 7 bits in order to encode these characters, maybe you can use [the wide character type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)?

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", "漢語");
    printf("%s\n", "ę");
}
```

output:

```
~$ gcc wcharexample.c -o wcharexample && ./wcharexample 
漢語
ę
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I need, but there is no such header file in XC8 SDK :(

Comment: This is implementation-dependent whether you can have wide characters in your source file; it's possible you may have to use unicode string literals to express them , even though the runtime support is there.

Comment: in Standard C use `wprintf` and wide literals, they are in stdio.h

Comment: @MattMcNabb wprintf? Im not using standard printf, this is embedded, I'm driving screen pixels directly by sending 8-pixel bytes from microprocessor/microcontroler to screen.

Comment: Somoene apparently ported a subset of these functions on pic32 from libc, maybe you can do the same on pic8? Or you can contact him :) http://www.microchip.com/forums/m735975.aspx?&tree=true# (last answer)